# List of dicts in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of dictionaries in python with every letter of a word in each dict.
This is my code:

```
words = ["bella","label","roller"]
list1 = [{}] * len(words)

for i in range(len(words)):
    for letter in words[i]:
        list1[i][letter] = 0

print(list1)
```

And this is my output:

```
[{'b': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 0, 'a': 0, 'r': 0, 'o': 0},
 {'b': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 0, 'a': 0, 'r': 0, 'o': 0},
 {'b': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 0, 'a': 0, 'r': 0, 'o': 0}]
```

Why don't I have a different dictionary for every word?

Comment: *with every letter of a word in each dict* -- so why your code has numbers?

Comment: Try `list1 = [{} for _ in words]` instead.

Comment: @Lei Yang I'm trying to count the letters but I'm stuck before I got to that

Comment: It would be helpful if you demonstrated your _expected_ output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to find common characters in each word, but first I tried to make a dictionary for each word

Comment: @StevieG25 if you want the common characters between these words without the number of occurrences, you can use ``set.intersection(*[set(word) for word in words])``.

Comment: j1 has the answer to your question. As to why your approach doesn't work...`[{}] * len(words)` first creates a list containing a dictionary, and then the repetition operator (`*`) makes copies of that list and merges them together. The repetition operator does a **shallow copy**, and so each of the created lists references the same map as its single value.  So you end up with a list of references to the same dictionary.  Using `[{} for _ in words]` gives you what you want because it's essentially a `for` loop, and so the `{}` is evaluated multiple times, each time creating a unique dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `collections.Counter`.

```py
from collections import Counter

words = ["bella", "label", "roller"]
letter_counts = [dict(Counter(word)) for word in words]
print(letter_counts)
```

*output*

> [{'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'a': 1}, {'l': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1},
> {'r': 2, 'o': 1, 'l': 2, 'e': 1}]

*update*

Your code doesn't work because `[{}] * len(words)` makes a list with items(dict) that have **same reference**. Updating the dict will affect all items in list. Just try this code

```py
lst = [{}] * 2
lst[0]['a'] = 2
lst[1]['a'] = 3
print(lst)
# [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3}]
```